# Notepad++ Monospace Fonts not working properly/ not really monospace - SOLUTION

Tags: themes, notepad, monospace

Notepad++ v6.9 is not displaying monospaced fonts properly. No matter what setting, the spaces have different width to the characters. Adjusting *Global Styles* in *settings - Style Configurator...* and *stylers.xml* didnt work.

**Gladly I found the solution at last!**

-> Look below

Answer (score 1):

**Solution Process**

So I was using Notepad++ v6.9 and I was having problems with the display of monospace fonts.

Going through all settings under *-Settings - Style Configurator...*, I couldnt get it running properly.

Everything I tried lead to the same result: The spaces were of different width than my font. The spaces even adjusted with the zoom. So

1. I tried setting explicitly setting a monospace font for my used style.
2. I tried setting the styles via the stylers.xml. I especially set the fontName and fontSize to be equal between GlobalStyles and my theme but to no avail.
3. I tried adding *fontStyle* and *fontSize* to all parameters of GlobalStyles but that broke the theme completely.
4. I tried decreasing the font size so that it would fit the spaces. First problem: You cant set the fontsize lower than 5 via the settings. But you can via the stylers.xml. Second problem: The fontsize needs to be smaller than 1 and stylers.xml does not accept "0,8" nor "0.8" nor 0.8. Got it to work with "09". To match the space size it was necessary to set the font to 0.1, which looked fine till: Third problem: The space width adjusts with zoom level, whereas the font does not. So this was a dead end.
5. **Next I stumbled upon the solution!** I deleted the stylers.xml and reloaded Notepad++ and suddenly there were a lot more settings under *Settings - Style Configurator... - Global Styles*. (*Enable global font, Enable global font size, Enable global font style, ...* were not available before) And now everything works as expected!

I write this because I saw a lot of people with similar problems but couldnt find a solution. So this is for anyone else that comes across the same problem and for me for future reference.

I would be happy if it was helpful to you, that you give a short comment so more people can see this!

Best regards